# Exposing an object variable as public makes its members unresolvable

Tags: kotlin

I have a Kotlin class with a member object:

```kotlin
private var strings = object { var foo = ""; var bar = "" }
```

Inside my class's functions, I can reference `strings.foo` and `strings.bar`.

But when I make `strings` a `public var`, suddenly all of its members become "unresolved references". Why?

```kotlin
class Foo {
    // Making this `private` fixes the errors below for some reason
    public var strings = object {
        var foo = ""
        var bar = ""
    }

    fun initialize() {
        strings.foo = getFoo()  // "Unresolved reference: foo"
        strings.bar = getBar()  // "Unresolved reference: bar"
    }
}
```

(What I'm trying to do here is expose a whole bunch of string resources as constants so I don't have to use the literal string values throughout my code. I'm actually using `lateinit var` for each member but that doesn't change the result here.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the field of top-level object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68690146/how-to-access-the-field-of-top-level-object)

Comment: For your use case, I would just do `object Strings { ... }` or `companion object Strings { ... }` and put all your constants in there. Your object _has_ a name, so make a named object! Or do you _really_ hate the extra type that this creates?

Comment: No -- in fact, I *wanted* the extra type that it creates. I've now learned the difference between an object *literal* and an object *declaration*. Thanks!

Comment: @Sweeper: yes, although IMO my question is slightly different (top-level vs exposed publicly in a class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strings` is defined with an [object literal](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#object-literals). You probably want to use an [regular object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#classifier-declaration) instead:

```kotlin
object Strings {...}
strings = Strings()
```

With the object literal, `strings` is an anonymous object whose type is "usable (and visible) only in the scope where it is declared".

without any explicitly declared supertype, menaing `Any` is implicit super type of this object.

When you make `strings` a `public var`, it escapes the current scope and is implicitly downcasted to its supertype; without any explicitly declared supertype, the supertype is `Any`, so of course you get errors trying to reference the properties `foo` and `bar`.

From [Kotlin spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#classifier-declaration)

> The main difference between a regular object declaration and an anonymous object is its type. The type of an anonymous object is a special kind of type which is usable (and visible) only in the scope where it is declared. It is similar to a type of a regular object declaration, but, as it cannot be used outside the declaring scope, has some interesting effects.

> When a value of an anonymous object type escapes current scope:

> 1. If the type has only one declared supertype, it is implicitly downcasted to this declared supertype;
> 2. If the type has several declared supertypes, there must be an implicit or explicit cast to any suitable type visible outside the scope, otherwise it is a compile-time error.

> Note: an implicit cast may arise, for example, from the results of type inference.

> Note: in this context “escaping current scope” is performed immediately if the corresponding value is declared as a non-private global- or classifier-scope property, as those are parts of an externally accessible interface.

You could also use a Companion object:

```
companion object Strings {
    var foo = ""
    var bar = ""
}

fun init(){
   foo = getFoo()
   bar = getBar()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted this but edited it to explain the "root cause" of my confusion: the difference between an (anonymous) object literal and a (regular) object declaration.