# Implementation method according to the access limiter of anonymous object

Tags: kotlin, object, anonymous-function

When an anonymous object is `public`, it is simply implemented as an object return, but when it is `private`, it is returned as a type-cast object. look at the Kotlin code below.

```kotlin
private fun foo() = object {
    val x: String = "x"
}

fun bar() = object {
    val x: String = "x"
}
```

When this code is decompiled into Java, it changes like this:

```java
private static final <undefinedtype> foo() {
    return (<undefinedtype>)(new Object() {
        @NotNull
        private final String x = "x";

        @NotNull
        public final String getX() {
            return this.x;
        }
    });
}

@NotNull
public static final Object bar() {
    return new Object() {
        @NotNull
        private final String x = "x";

        @NotNull
        public final String getX() {
            return this.x;
        }
    };
}
```

Therefore, when you try to use the code, only the `private` anonymous object can access `x`.

[image: code]

So, why do each access modifiers have different implementations?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68690146/5133585).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how language defines the semantics of anonymous objects.

Type of an anonymous object is only usable in the declaring scope, when you use `public` modifier, anonymous object escapes the current scope and is cast to `Any` (implicit super type). since `Any` doesn't have any property `x`, you can't access it.
on the other hand when you use `private` modifier you make sure that it doesn't escape the current scope.

From the [Kotlin language specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#object-literals)

> The main difference between a regular object declaration and an
> anonymous object is its type. ***The type of an anonymous object is a
> special kind of type which is usable (and visible) only in the scope
> where it is declared.*** It is similar to a type of a regular object
> declaration, but, as it cannot be used outside the declaring scope,
> has some interesting effects.
>
> When a value of an anonymous object type escapes current scope:
>
> 1. If the type has only one declared supertype, it is implicitly downcasted to this declared supertype;
> 2. If the type has several declared supertypes, there must be an implicit or explicit cast to any suitable type visible outside the
>    scope, otherwise it is a compile-time error.
>
> ***Note: in this context “escaping current scope” is performed
> immediately if the corresponding value is declared as a non-private
> global*** or classifier-scope property, as those are parts of an
> externally accessible interface.