# Returning anonymous object from function and infering type in Kotlin

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, generics, dsl

I'm coming from Java and am new to Kotlin. I am trying to create declarative DSL for unit testing purposes. Here is my attempt to create generic builder method to construct any model object with declarative syntax.

```
fun <T> having(t: Class<T>) = object {
    infix fun with(fn: T.() -> Unit) = t.newInstance().apply(fn)
}

fun test() {

    having(Pizza::class.java) with {
        size = Size.NORMAL
        cheese = Cheese.MOZARELLA
    }
}
```

However, the `having` function returns `Any` type with unresolved reference to `with` function. I could extract the anonymous object to it's own class to make it compile, but it would feel redundant. Is it possible to resort on the type inference with functions returning an `object` instances?

Also, I'm not sure if I'm using generics the idiomatic way here.

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68690146/how-to-access-the-field-of-top-level-object/68690375#68690375). The way to fix it would be to make `having` a `private` function, but I think that'd be undesirable for you. I would suggest that you make a new class for this object.

Comment: Also, isn't this just an `Pizza().apply { ... }` with extra steps? And have you considered other syntax forms like `Pizza::class.with { ... }` or `Pizza::class with { ... }`? Basically, I don't understand what the point of the `having` call is.

Comment: @Sweeper I like the `Pizza::class.with { ... }` syntax, but I'm not sure how I would add generic extension method instantiating the class to `class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the `having` function's return type being inferred as `Any` is explained in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68690146/how-to-access-the-field-of-top-level-object/68690375#68690375). Basically, you'll have to make `having` `private` in order to make it infer the desired return type. Obviously, that's not a viable solution for you unit testing DSL, which is going to be used by code in other files.

You can consider dropping the word `having`, and directly declare `with` as an extension/infix function on `KClass` instead.

Extension function:

```
fun <T: Any> KClass<T>.with(fn: T.() -> Unit) = this.createInstance().apply(fn)

// ...

Pizza::class.with {
    size = Size.NORMAL
    cheese = Cheese.MOZZARELLA
}
```

Infix function:

```
infix fun <T: Any> KClass<T>.with(fn: T.() -> Unit) = this.createInstance().apply(fn)

fun main() {

    Pizza::class with {
        size = Size.NORMAL
        cheese = Cheese.MOZZARELLA
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning an `object` of unspecified type, you can return a wrapping object, which declares the `with` function and contains the original class object.

This way you get type safety, while retaining you `having`-style DSL.

```kotlin
data class WrappedInstance<T>(val data: T) {
    infix fun with(applyFn: T.() -> Unit): T = data.also(applyFn)
}

fun <T : Any> having(kClass: KClass<T>): WrappedInstance<T> =
    WrappedInstance(kClass.createInstance())
```

Using it, looks like this:

```kotlin
data class Pizza(var size: Int = 1, var cheese: Int = 1)

fun test() {
    val pizza: Pizza = having(Pizza::class) with {
        size = 3
        cheese = 5
    }
    
    println(pizza.size)
    println(pizza.cheese)
}
```

---

Please be aware, that this as well as your original approach both have a caveat though. They only work for classes with constructors, that don't require any parameter.

See the documentation of `KClass<T>.createInstance()`:

> Creates a new instance of the class, calling a constructor which either has no parameters or all parameters of which are optional (see KParameter.isOptional). If there are no or many such constructors, an exception is thrown.

---

When theres no need for the `having` part of the DSL, check out [@Sweeper's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70196790/3160089).